# Is there a Netbeans profile view like Eclipse: Switching to debugging/testing layout

Tags: java, debugging, layout, netbeans, junit

I'm building a JSF web application with Netbeans. Is there a way to easily switch the layout to better accommodate for debugging, unit-testing and gui layout?

More specifically, when I'm building unit test or debugging I like to "undock" the output, debugging, and Test results windows and place them on my second screen. But when working with the HTML side I need the open screen for a web browser. So I would like to structure my layout in different ways to accommodate what I'm currently doing. This is a feature of eclipse but I can't seem to find any way to do it in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Netbeans has that feature. As you specified, we can only undock the windows.